# Custom Toggle Button: How to prevent text overlapping with icon

Tags: android, user-interface, padding, android-drawable, togglebutton

I'm trying to make a custom toggle button, where the icon is considerably larger than the original built-in one.
I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
    *-------------------*
    *  *------------*   *
    *  *            *   *
    *  *   Icon     *   *
    *  *            *   *
    *  *------------*   *
    *  *------------*   *
    *  *    Text    *   *
    *  *------------*   *
    *-------------------*
```

So this is my button:

```
    <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="18dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_toggle_layer"
            android:gravity="bottom | center_horizontal"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CustomTBText"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textOff="@string/tb_off"
            android:textOn="@string/tb_on" />
```

The custom background is defined in `drawable/custom_toggle_layer.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <item android:id="@+android:id/background"   
              android:drawable="@drawable/custom_toggle_bg" /> 
        <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" 
              android:drawable="@drawable/custom_toggle_icon" /> 
    </layer-list>
```

Where `custom_toggle_bg` and `custom_toggle_icon` are both selectors and are working fine.

The problem is the text is overlapping with the bottom side of the icon. The text is aligned to the bottom, and if I make the icon larger the text sticks to the bottom of the button correctly.

I first tried to set a padding on the toggle button, but this just moves the text up inside the icon yet a bit more.

I'm trying to style the text independently of the button, so I've defined a custom style:

```
    <style name="CustomTBText">
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item><!-- This works -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item><!-- This works -->

        <item name="android:paddingTop">15dp</item><!-- This does not work -->
    </style>
```

And tried to set a top padding to the text only, but that attribute does not work (the other attributes in the style work fine).

How can I fix this? I could do a hack setting the text of the button to empty and using an external TextView, but if possible I'd like to do everything using a customized ToggleButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What most tutorials on custom toggle buttons do is to set a layer list as a background to the whole button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"   
          android:drawable="@drawable/custom_toggle_bg" /> 
    <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/custom_toggle_icon" /> 
</layer-list>
```

This causes problems with the text (and that's also why most tutorials do not show text).
So what I did is to set `custom_toggle_bg` as background and  `custom_toggle_icon` as drawableTop, and now it works. This is the button fixed:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_toggle_bg"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/custom_toggle_icon"
        android:gravity="bottom | center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="@style/CustomTBText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textOff="@string/tb_off"
        android:textOn="@string/tb_on" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the drawable's position, like drawableLeft, drawableTop, drawabeRight, drawableBottom and drawableStart depending on were you want to see the icon.

Regards!